# the IF(OR) statement

Tags: 2007, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to nest **6** IF(OR) statements in SP 2007 for a calculated field in a list - But it seems as if it is getting too long, and I get the syntax error thrown at me. I tested half of the length and that went fine,the other half as well, however it seems to go wrong at some point after the appending of 4th IF.. I would really appreciate any help to make this work! :)

```
=IF(OR([Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project    ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project  ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"HEY","")&IF(OR([Project  ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"YO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"HI","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"HELLO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"MJALLO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x",[Project ID]="x"),"BYE","")
```

(project IDs are x'ed out for simplicity - they are all different IRL)

Comment: Have you tried it in Excel?

Comment: NOPE-Mostly because I dont need it working in excell :)

Comment: formulas for calculated fields are based on Microsoft Excel functions and syntax : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I know this.. but since both halves work seperately, the syntax is clearly correct so why test in excell? I am looking for an answer to how to make SP 2007 accept more than  3 concatenated IF's

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I deleted the previous answer. Now I'm back in the office in a SP environment where I can test. This worked for me:

```
=IF(OR([Project ID]="A1",[Project ID]="A1",[Project ID]="A1",[Project ID]="A1",[Project ID]="A2",[Project ID]="A2",[Project ID]="A2",[Project ID]="A2",[Project ID]="A3",[Project ID]="A3",[Project ID]="A3",[Project ID]="A3",[Project ID]="A3"),"HEY","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="B1",[Project ID]="B1",[Project ID]="B1",[Project ID]="B2",[Project ID]="B2",[Project ID]="B3",[Project ID]="B3"),"YO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="C1",[Project ID]="C1",[Project ID]="C1",[Project ID]="C2",[Project ID]="C2",[Project ID]="C2",[Project ID]="C2",[Project ID]="C3",[Project ID]="C3",[Project ID]="C3",[Project ID]="C3",[Project ID]="C4",[Project ID]="C4",[Project ID]="C4",[Project ID]="C4",[Project ID]="C5",[Project ID]="C5",[Project ID]="C5",[Project ID]="C5",[Project ID]="C6",[Project ID]="C6"),"HI","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="D1",[Project ID]="D1",[Project ID]="D1",[Project ID]="D2",[Project ID]="D2",[Project ID]="",[Project ID]="D2",[Project ID]="D3",[Project ID]="D3",[Project ID]="D3"),"HELLO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="E1",[Project ID]="E1",[Project ID]="E1",[Project ID]="E2",[Project ID]="E2",[Project ID]="E2",[Project ID]="E2"),"MJALLO","")&IF(OR([Project ID]="F1",[Project ID]="F1",[Project ID]="F2",[Project ID]="F3"),"BYE","")
```

I change dthe "x" with different values. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Looks alot like the stuff I already have.. ? except all my project IDs are different from each other..is there a syntax difference that I missed? :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply - I've not been able to comment earlier

Comment: Initially, the only issue I found in your code was spacing. If you notice I edited it when I saw those extra spaces. But the rest remained pretty much the same.

Comment: are you testing in SP 2007?

Comment: Actually 2010, but it should be the same. Also I tested on MS Excel.

Answer (score 0):

there is a limitation for no of if statements for SharePoint calculated field. refer this article : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/introduction-to-data-calculations-HA010121588.aspx

and best alternative to overcome your issue will be use choose statements or to use multiple calculated columns.and keep in mind that there is a limitation of 102 characters also.

Comment: if this was helpful or if it's the answer you expect let me know